# Can I File TN Visa Extension Myself

Tags: tn-visa

My understanding is to extend a TN visa for a Canadian citizen requires filing an I-129 form. Can I submit this form myself or does an employer have to submit it on my behalf?

Answer (score 1):

The [I-129](https://www.uscis.gov/i-129) is a petition for a nonimmigrant worker.  The [instructions for the form](https://www.uscis.gov/system/files_force/files/form/i-129instr-pc.pdf) make it clear that the petition must be submitted by the employer.  There are some exceptions, but none of those exceptions involves a beneficiary submitting the petition on his or her own behalf:

> Who May File Form I-129?
>
> General. A U.S. employer may file this form and applicable supplements to classify an alien in any nonimmigrant classification listed in Part 1. or Part 2. of these instructions. A foreign employer, U.S. agent, or association of U.S. agricultural employers may file for certain classifications as indicated in the specific instructions.